# Taking a String that is a Date and Formatting it in Java

Tags: java, date, format

I have a String in Java which is a date but is formatted like:

**02122012**

I need to reformat it to look like **02/12/2012** how can this be done.

With the following code I keep getting back **java.text.SimpleDateFormat@d936eac0**

Below is my code..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Make a String that has a date in it, with MEDIUM date format
    // and SHORT time format.
    String dateString = "02152012";

    SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        output.format(input.parse(dateString));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```

Comment: Agree with Alex, and even if that's meant to be 02122012, what have you tried?

Comment: @BlueBullet: You've edited the original question *assuming* it's just a typo. I'd rather hear that from the OP.

Comment: I keep getting back java.text.SimpleDateFormat@d936eac0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(output.format(input.parse("02122012"))); // 02/12/2012
```

As suggested by Jon Skeet, you can also set the `TimeZone` and `Locale` on the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat englishUtcDateFormat(String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return sdf;
}

SimpleDateFormat input = englishUtcDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
SimpleDateFormat output = englishUtcDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(output.format(input.parse("02122012"))); // 02/12/2012
```

Comment: I would suggest specifying the time zone as UTC and the locale as English, and possibly even setting the calendar explicitly too.

Comment: it did not work... I got java.text.SimpleDateFormat@d936eac0 if I do a output.toString()

Comment: @techsjs2012: See my answer for what you're doing wrong in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the code in your edited question:

```
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

You're printing out the `SimpleDateFormat`, not the result of calling `format`. Indeed, you're *ignoring* the result of calling `format`:

```
output.format(input.parse(dateString));
```

Just change it to:

```
System.out.println(output.format(input.parse(dateString)));
```

Or more clearly:

```
Date parsedDate = input.parse(dateString);
String reformattedDate = output.format(parsedDate);
System.out.println(reformattedDate);
```